# Why does the meetup oauth2 callback put the query string into a hashtag?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

When I get the callback from meetup, using their oauth2 api, I am given the following URL

```
http://127.0.0.1/login/meetup/#expires_in=3600&token_type=bearer&access_token=08548035608352890
```

Is this a mistake that they return a # instead of a ? in the query string? If not, how can I handle this in django? I printed the response object, and the only useful information I could find is

```
'method': 'GET',
'path': '/login/meetup/',
```

unless, I accidentally glanced over something.

Comment: You shouldn't put your access token into messages like this as it can be misused. I'd recommend revoking application access, or generating a new one.

Comment: thanks for catching that one, it's been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is because Meetup saves this information in a [url fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) so that only a client side application can access this information. Meetup states

```
The response parameters listed in the server flow's success (with the exception 
of refresh_token) and failure access token responses will be included in the 
implicit authorization's client response appended as a url fragment. Because 
this information is encoded in a url fragment, it can only be retrieved with 
client-side browser scripts.
```

here http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/auth/#oauth2implicit